# In the rstanarm package, is there a way to incorporate random effects in the stan_glm function?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, stan

I am wondering if there was an option to incorporate random effects in the `stan_glm` function in the `rstanarm` package within `R`.

I currently have large amounts of code written in the `stan_glm` formula, and when I wanted to add random effects, was surprised to see that it didn't contain it by default. Is there a way to do it by adding in another function or would I need to do something like this completely by hand? Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at `stan_glmer` ... ???

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! Is `stan_glmer` equivalent to `stan_glm` if I do not incorporate random effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `stan_glmer` function, or `stan_gamm4` if you want to use smooth functions of predictors.

Comment: Thanks! Is `stan_glmer` equivalent to `stan_glm` if I do not incorporate random effects?

Comment: Yes, aside from the error message when you call `stan_glmer` with a formula that does not include `(... | g)`.

Comment: If I use the `stan_gamm4` function, does it do everything `stan_glmer` and `stan_glm` does? In other words, is it the generalization of both of these?

Comment: Pretty much, but you have to specify the `random` argument separately from the formula, unlike `stan_glmer`.